# Fetching the tag values on selector

Tags: ios, tags, uibutton

I am working with the iphone project. In that i added 3 buttons with same selector name(i.e action). Now i am fetch the data from the database using the query. But it is showing me the data to 3rd button only when i am pressing any butoon out of three .

```
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(80, 30, 200, 50);
[btn.layer setBorderWidth:0];
btn.tag = 1;
[btn setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(detail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:14.0];
[scrollview addSubview:btn];


btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(80, 30, 200, 50);
[btn.layer setBorderWidth:0];
btn.tag = 2;
[btn setTitle:@"2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(detail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:14.0];
[scrollview addSubview:btn];


btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(80, 30, 200, 50);
[btn.layer setBorderWidth:0];
btn.tag = 3;
[btn setTitle:@"3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(detail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:14.0];
[scrollview addSubview:btn];
```

this is the action which i am using.

```
-(IBAction)detail:(id)sender
{
    detailViewController *detailvc =[[detailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"detailViewController" bundle:Nil];
     detailvc.btntxt = btn.tag;
    NSLog(@"name of btn :%ld",(long)btn.tag);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailvc animated:YES];
}
```

In nslog also i am getting the tab of 3rd button only
please help me out regarding this issue...

Comment: You should not use same tag for all 3 buttons

Comment: sry it was by mistake i am having different tag values.....

Comment: are all these button in same position? CGRectMake(80, 30, 200, 50)? please paste your raw code so everyone can see what's the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning 1 tag to a button

```
btn.tag = 1;
```

add different tag to each button

--

Also in your `detail:` take the tag from the sender and not your instance variable

```
 - (IBAction)detail:(UIButton *)sender {
    detailViewController *detailvc =[[detailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"detailViewController" bundle:Nil];
    detailvc.btntxt = sender.tag;
    NSLog(@"name of btn :%ld",(long) sender.tag);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailvc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: so vote up and mark your question as solved so that Hani get his reputation ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You set the tag number of all 3 buttons to the same value (1). You need to use different values if you want to be able to tell your buttons apart.

Use tag 1 for the first button, tag 2 for the second, and tag 3 for the third.

Comment: I think the question is already using three different tags as 1,2 & 3. The main problem is that the `btn` object is just single. All three tags has been assigned to a signle object, that's why the last tag is getting reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sender` variable to get the button that triggered the action:

```
-(IBAction)detail:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSInteger buttonTag = button.tag;
    // etc
}
```

Also, give each button it's own tag

```
btn.tag = 2; // and 3
```

And don't use the `btn` variable in the action method. It will only ever contain the last set variable, which is the third button in this case.

Comment: Also all the button instances are same, i.e `btn`. Ideally three different variables should be used.

Comment: @BalramTiwari I don't think that will make a difference. Each new button is given to the scroll view by `addSubview`. The variable can be reused without a problem. The face that `btn` seems to be an ivar is a problem though (should be a methods variable).

Comment: Oh, that's right. Agreed, The btn should be local to the method.

Answer (score 0):

just use `((UIButton)sender).tag` instead of `btn.tag`

Comment: I guess you have missed `*`

Kindly update it as ((UIButton * )sender).tag
As I am not able to edit.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you are using just single button object ( & initializing it three times & adding three different tags & adding it to subviews.), which looks like an ivar.

So even if you have added three different tags to a single object instance the recent most will be reflected & so you are getting just 3 as tag, all time.

```
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
....
btn.tag = 1;
.
.
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
...
btn.tag = 2;
.
.
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
...
btn.tag = 3
```

Instead you either don't use btn object in ur target method or you can have three different buttons for a good understanding.

```
UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 30, 200, 50);
....
btn1.tag = 1;
.
.
UIButton *btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn2.frame = CGRectMake(80, 80, 200, 50);
...
btn2.tag = 2;
.
.
UIButton* btn3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn3.frame = CGRectMake(80, 130, 200, 50);
...
btn3.tag = 3
```

Rest you need to modify the code of the target method as

```
-(IBAction)detail:(UIButton *)sender
{
    detailViewController *detailvc =[[detailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"detailViewController" bundle:Nil];
     detailvc.btntxt = sender.tag;
    NSLog(@"name of btn :%ld",(long)sender.tag);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailvc animated:YES];
}
```

I hope this will certainly help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)detail:(UIButton*)sender
{  
 if(sender.tag==1)
 {

 }
 else if(sender.tag==2)
 {

 }
 else if(sender.tag==3)
 {

 }
}
```